# Remove transition and delay of Bootstrap 4 Collapse element

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to remove the transition and the delay of the Bootstrap 4 Collapse element.
I'm using CSS to remove the transition itself:

```
.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    display: none;
}

#collapseExample {background: red;}
```

That part works fine. But there is still some delay before the Collapse element shows. Is there any way to remove that?

Here's the HTML:

Navbar

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Button with data-target
</button>
</form>
</div>
</nav>


<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
<div class="container">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you try .collapsing {
  transition: none !important;
}

Comment: yes, doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying a transition on the 'collapsing' class, which is added after the transition begins, and removed when it's ending. Instead of placing the override on this class, place it on the actual element, or the main class which doesn't gets changed.

From the documentation:

> Usage
>   The collapse plugin utilizes a few classes to handle the heavy lifting:
>
> `.collapse` hides the content
>
> `.collapse.show` shows the content
>
> `.collapsing` is added when the transition starts, and removed when it finishes
>
> These classes can be found in _transitions.scss.

Simply add the following line to your CSS:

`#collapseExample {transition: none; background: red;}`

[Link to docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Comment: thanks for your answer! But adding the css to the classes above doesn't help either :(

Comment: Could you share the HTML structure in your initial question in that case?

Comment: I added the HTML to my question

Comment: I’m not behind my desk, give me 20 minutes and i’ll update :)

Comment: Adding the line `#collapseExample {transition: none; background: red;}` works for me, see: https://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/XqWVoN?editors=1101

Comment: I'm importing Bootstrap JS inside the codepen, in addition to Bootstrap's CSS & jQuery

Comment: you're right. but why is the navbar broken? On my site it doesn't work because the div already has `transition: none;` from `.collapse`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to keep animation you can use and this is case when u have color on navbar

```
.navbar {
   transition: ease-in .3s;
}
```